# Using :not with :active (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was wondering where about `:not` is suppose to go in this code?

```
outerBox:active .innerBox {display: block;}
```

Where `outerBox` is the first element and `innerBox` `middleBox` are childs(?) of it.

When I click anywhere in the `outerBox` I want it to display the `innerBox` unless it the click is too close to centre in the `middleBox` (so `:not(middleBox)` or something like that).

Can someone please tell me how/where to use the :not?

Thanks,
Hello2215 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can append various pseudoselectors.

```
.outerBox:active:not(.not-class) .innerBox {display: block;}
```

Comment: You can share your HTML with us, because we need to see the structure to know the desired behaviour. This selector works, another question is if you need it or how do you need it.

Comment: I worked around it by using another active which displays: none after the first

Comment: I don't know what you try to tell me, but if you solve it please, make this answer as valid. The selector works fine :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
.outerBox:active:not(:not(X)) .innerBox {display: block;}
```

**Syntax**

```
:not(selector) { style properties }
```

[Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

See the page [Example](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)